# Cannot resolve maven dependency

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have written a custom plugin and I deploy it to an internal company repository.  I have another project that uses the plugin (here is the pom.xml snippet):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.mypackage</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-generator-main</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                   <phase>package</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>json-schema-generator-main</goal>
                   </goals>
                   </execution>
              </executions>
          </plugin>
     </plugins>
</build>
```

I deploy my custom plugin to our internal repo and my local one successfully. If I remove it from my local repo, however, when I run "mvn clean install" in the dependent project I get the following output:

```
[ERROR] Plugin com.mycompan.mypackage:json-schema-generator-main:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.mycompany.mypackage:json-schema-generator-main:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT ->
```

What could be causing this behavior?  I'm happy to provide more information, such as the details of my custom plugin, which uses a lot of reflection and classpath hackery to generate Json Schema text files, or it's pom.xml, but I'm not sure what would be relevant without turning this into a wall of text.  As best I can tell it is correctly deployed in the repo, and this problem only occurs if you remove the custom plugin from your local repository.

Comment: Is your plugin in your maven repository?

Comment: Yes.  Sorry, see new edits.  It is definitely in the internal maven repository, and this only happens when delete it from my local repository.

Comment: Did you add your company repo to `settings.xml` or `pom.xml`? If you install your plugin in your local repo (in your machine!) with `mvn install`, it will not look at your company repo to use it, but in the local. After you delete the plugin from your local repo, seems it is not looking at your company repo - or don't have access.

Comment: I had a versioning issue in my deployment to the internal repository.  The files were not being properly named and therefore obviously could not be found.  I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

Answered in comments:

> I had a versioning issue in my deployment to the internal repository.
>   The files were not being properly named and therefore obviously could
>   not be found. I apologize. –  Jesse Aug 14 '14 at 19:12